# Most canonical way to compile a tex file with and without serif?

Tags: pdftex, sans-serif

I seek a very light way to compile a tex document into two pdfs:

<...>_with_serif.pdf and <...>_without_serif.pdf

**hello.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}

% some .tex magic here ? (...)
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

\begin{document}
  hello !
\end{document}
```

**test.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# (...) and some bash magic here ?
with=???
without=???

for option in "$with" "$without"; do
  pdflatex $option hello.tex &>/dev/null
  mv hello.pdf "hello_$option.pdf"
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the package `ifthen` and the following texcode:

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\jobname}{serif}}{}{
  \renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
}
```

Then you would call it in your bash file as (I don't know bash that well, but you give the jobname as string parameter):

```
with="-jobname=serif"
without="-jobname=sans"
```

Comment: Slight change, comparing jobname is not that easy: use http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-compjobnam.html instead of the given answer, anyway it was the right direction :)